# Finding multiple numerations of a character in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextview

I am a `UITextView` where I am trying to find the `@` character. The text view might have multiple `@`s, so I was wondering, how can I find the nth `@` character?

Currently, I have: `NSRange range = [textViewText rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@"]];`. This only finds the first `@` instance. How can I find subsequent ones?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like splitting up the text based on `@"@"` and then you know where the components are split, thats where the `@` should appear.  This way you can easily find the `nth` `@`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you question correctly, a regular expression would solve you problem.
RegEx has a bit of a learning curve but it comes in handy very often.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/
is a very good starting point for regular expressions in general

http://remarkablepixels.com/blog/2011/1/13/regular-expressions-on-ios-nsregularexpression.html
A tutorial about regular expression in iOS

http://reggyapp.com/
Reggy is an osx app in which you can test your RegEx on actual text.

Comment: A RegExp seems a very heavy handed way of handling a simple problem like this.

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to do once you've located the nth `@`?

Here's some sample code that sketches a solution. Not compiled or checked for bugs!

```
int targetItem = 3; // we find the 3rd item 

NSString *workingStr = @"your@string@containing@stuff";

int foundAtLocation = -1;
for (int idx = 0; idx < targetItem; idx++) {
    NSRange range = [workingStr rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@"]];
    if (range.location < 0) {
        // not found, give up
        foundAtLocation = -1;
        break;
    }
    workingStr = [workingStr substringFromIndex:range.location];
    foundAtLocation += range.location;
}
if (foundAtLocation >= 0) {
    NSLog(@" I found the %d occurence of @ at character index %d", targetItem, foundAtLocation);
}
else {
    NSLog(@" Not found");
}
```

Comment: A comment as to the reason for the down-vote would be appreciated.